# CakePHP3 Multi Checkbox custom attribute

Tags: cakephp-3.0, formhelper, custom-attribute

I am using the the Cake

```
<?= $this->Form->input('vehicles._ids', ['label' => 'Vehicle', 'options' => $vehicles, 'multiple' => 'checkbox', 'ng-model' => 'vehicles']); ?>
```

For each check box I want to add the custom attributes: 'ng-model'

I can see that the generation of multiple checkboxes is handled by the class file MultiCheckboxwidget.php and checkboxes use the 'checkbox' template:

```
'checkbox' => '<input type="checkbox" name="{{name}}" value="{{value}}"{{attrs}}>',
```

But since by default this uses {{attrs}} I can't see why my custom ng-model attribute isn't being added to the generatred form input. Instead this is the amrk-up crearted by the helper:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicles[_ids][]" value="1"id="vehicles-ids-1" class="ng-valid">
```

How can I add ng-model to each of the checkbox inputs?

Comment: The fact that a `class` attribute with `ng-valid` is present, would make me belive that you are either not looking at the actual HTML output, but that you are inspecting the DOM which has been further manipulated at runtime, or that there is more relevant code that you're not showing. Please make sure that you are looking at the static page source, that you're providing all relevant code, and also please always mention the exact CakePHP version that you are using (your code works as expected with CakePHP 3.4.2).

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading my verison of CakePHP form 3.3.12 to 3.4 resolved the issue, the formhelper must have been refined in the latter versions.